# Mongooseim 3.6.0 postgress connection Issue

Tags: postgresql, installation, local, mongoose-im

Hi I am new to mongooseim , I am planing to setup mongooseim in my local setup with postgres database connection. I have installed mongooseim 3.6.0 in ubuntu 14.04 machine. And create database in postgres & add the schema for that.Then I have done the following changes in mongooseim.cfg file.

```
{outgoing_pools, [
  {rdbms, global, default, [{workers, 1}], [{server, {psql, "localhost", 5432, "mongooseim", "postgres", "password"}}]}
]}.
```

And this one.

```
{rdbms_server_type, pgsql}.
```

These are the changes I have done for default config file. Then When I restart the server it gives this error. postgres server running & user credentials are working.

```
020-06-05 18:17:46.815 [info] <0.249.0> msg: "Starting reporters with []\n", options: []
2020-06-05 18:17:47.034 [notice] <0.130.0>@lager_file_backend:143 Changed loglevel of /var/log/mongooseim/ejabberd.log to info
2020-06-05 18:17:47.136 [info] <0.43.0> Application mnesia exited with reason: stopped
2020-06-05 18:17:47.621 [error] <0.593.0>@mongoose_rdbms_psql:connect CRASH REPORT Process <0.593.0> with 0 neighbours crashed with reason: call to undefined function mongoose_rdbms_psql:connect({psql,"server",5432,"mongooseim","postgres","password"}, 5000)
2020-06-05 18:17:47.621 [error] <0.592.0>@mongoose_rdbms_psql:connect Supervisor 'wpool_pool-mongoose_wpool$rdbms$global$default-process-sup' had child 'wpool_pool-mongoose_wpool$rdbms$global$default-1' started with wpool_process:start_link('wpool_pool-mongoose_wpool$rdbms$global$default-1', mongoose_rdbms, [{server,{psql,"server",5432,"mongooseim","postgres","password"}}], [{queue_manager,'wpool_pool-mongoose_wpool$rdbms$global$default-queue-manager'},{time_checker,'wpool_pool-mongoose_wpool$rdbms$global$default-time-checker'},...]) at undefined exit with reason call to undefined function mongoose_rdbms_psql:connect({psql,"server",5432,"mongooseim","postgres","password"}, 5000) in context start_error
2020-06-05 18:17:47.622 [error] <0.589.0> Supervisor 'mongoose_wpool$rdbms$global$default' had child 'wpool_pool-mongoose_wpool$rdbms$global$default-process-sup' started with wpool_process_sup:start_link('mongoose_wpool$rdbms$global$default', 'wpool_pool-mongoose_wpool$rdbms$global$default-process-sup', [{queue_manager,'wpool_pool-mongoose_wpool$rdbms$global$default-queue-manager'},{time_checker,'wpool_pool-mongoose_wpool$rdbms$global$default-time-checker'},...]) at undefined exit with reason {shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,'wpool_pool-mongoose_wpool$rdbms$global$default-1',{undef,[{mongoose_rdbms_psql,connect,[{psql,"server",5432,"mongooseim","postgres","password"},5000],[]},{mongoose_rdbms,connect,4,[{file,"/root/deb/mongooseim/_build/prod/lib/mongooseim/src/rdbms/mongoose_rdbms.erl"},{line,668}]},{mongoose_rdbms,init,1,[{file,"/root/deb/mongooseim/_build/prod/lib/mongooseim/src/rdbms/mongoose_rdbms.erl"},{line,431}]},{wpool_process,init,1,[{file,"/root/deb/mongooseim/_build/..."},...]},...]}}} in context start_error
2020-06-05 18:17:47.622 [error] <0.583.0>@mongoose_wpool_mgr:handle_call:105 Pool not started: {error,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,'wpool_pool-mongoose_wpool$rdbms$global$default-process-sup',{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,'wpool_pool-mongoose_wpool$rdbms$global$default-1',{undef,[{mongoose_rdbms_psql,connect,[{psql,"server",5432,"mongooseim","postgres","password"},5000],[]},{mongoose_rdbms,connect,4,[{file,"/root/deb/mongooseim/_build/prod/lib/mongooseim/src/rdbms/mongoose_rdbms.erl"},{line,668}]},{mongoose_rdbms,init,1,[{file,"/root/deb/mongooseim/_build/prod/lib/mongooseim/src/rdbms/mongoose_rdbms.erl"},{line,431}]},{wpool_process,init,1,[{file,"/root/deb/mongooseim/_build/default/lib/worker_pool/src/wpool_process.erl"},{line,85}]},{gen_server,init_it,2,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,374}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,342}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]}}}}},{child,undefined,'mongoose_wpool$rdbms$global$default',{wpool,start_pool,['mongoose_wpool$rdbms$global$default',[{worker,{mongoose_rdbms,[{server,{psql,"server",5432,"mongooseim","postgres","password"}}]}},{pool_sup_shutdown,infinity},{workers,1}]]},temporary,infinity,supervisor,[wpool]}}}
2020-06-05 18:17:47.678 [warning] <0.615.0>@service_mongoose_system_metrics:report_transparency:129 We are gathering the MongooseIM system's metrics to analyse the trends and needs of our users, improve MongooseIM, and know where to focus our efforts. For more info on how to customise, read, enable, and disable these metrics visit: 
- MongooseIM docs - 
      https://mongooseim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operation-and-maintenance/System-Metrics-Privacy-Policy/ 
- MongooseIM GitHub page - https://github.com/esl/MongooseIM 
The last sent report is also written to a file /var/log/mongooseim/system_metrics_report.json
2020-06-05 18:17:48.404 [warning] <0.1289.0>@nkpacket_stun:get_stun_servers:231 Current NAT is changing ports!
```